# Show "loading" popup while page is generated

Tags: c#, popup, spinner, maui, loading

I'm trying to get a popup to appear while the app downloads data from the database and the page is generated/refreshed.

Maybe I lack the knowledge necessary to understand the order in which the instructions are executed or if the problem lies in the incorrect handling of animations.

I call the same popup on different project pages. In some cases it works and in others it is not shown at all.

PopUp.cs

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views;

namespace FZ102;

public partial class PopupPageLoading : Popup
{
    public PopupPageLoading()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void Dismiss()
    {
        // End the appearance transition.
        //endAppearanceTransition();

        // Dismiss the popup.
        DismissAsync();
    }

     void DismissAsync()
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

PopUp xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<toolkit:Popup
    x:Class="FZ102.PopupPageLoading"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    Size="300, 300"
    CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup="False">
    <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="5">
        <Image
            Margin="0"
            HeightRequest="300"
            IsAnimationPlaying="True"
            Source="FZ102loading.gif"
            WidthRequest="300" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</toolkit:Popup>
```

Page's call

```cs
public void RiempioSettimana(DateTime DP)
{

    PopupPageLoading p = new PopupPageLoading();
    Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopup(p);


    ModelloAgendaDisponibilita DisponibilitaSettimana = new ModelloAgendaDisponibilita;
    string DateInStriga = "";

    DateInStriga = "20" + L_Lun.Text[^2..] + L_Lun.Text[^5..^3] + L_Lun.Text[^8..^6];
    DisponibilitaSettimana = ScaricoGiorno(DateInStriga);

    if (DisponibilitaSettimana != null)
    {
        if (DisponibilitaSettimana.Stato == "Libero") F_C1R1.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(ColoreLibero);
        else
         if (DisponibilitaSettimana.Stato == "Offerto") F_C1R1.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(ColoreOffertoMaLibero);

    }
    else
    {
        F_C1R1.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(ColoreLibero);
    }
    p.Close();
}


private ModelloAgendaDisponibilita ScaricoGiorno(string DataInStringa)
{
    ModelloAgendaDisponibilita DR = new ModelloAgendaDisponibilita { Stato = "Vuoto" };

    DR = Libreria.EstraggoModelloAgendaDisponibilita(UserNameRicevuto, path, DataInStringa);

    return DR;
}
```

Connection to DB

```cs
public static ModelloAgendaDisponibilita EstraggoModelloAgendaDisponibilita(string UserName, string path, string DataInStringa)
{
    FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.CreateAsync("****").Result;
    DocumentReference DocumentoEstratto = db.Collection("***").Document(UserName).Collection(DataInStringa).Document(DataInStringa);
    DocumentSnapshot snap = DocumentoEstratto.GetSnapshotAsync().Result;
    ModelloAgendaDisponibilita DR = snap.ConvertTo<ModelloAgendaDisponibilita>();
    return (DR);
}
```

(Maybe the fact that it's a synchronous call is a problem?)

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is to use [ActivityIndicator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/activityindicator)

```xml
<ActivityIndicator x:Name="loadingIndicator" IsRunning="False" />
```

And you stop it and start it with `loadingIndicator.IsRunning = true;`

To make this more interested you can make a modal page like a popup and show whatever content you like using [Navigation.PushModalAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/navigationpage#perform-modal-navigation) that pushes a page on top of the stack and as easily you can remove it. Here is an eaxmple:

```cs
var page = new LoadingPage();
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);

await Task.Delay(5000);

await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
```

**LoadingPage**

```cs
public class LoadingPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoadingPage()
    {
        BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;

        Content = new Grid
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            WidthRequest = 200,
            HeightRequest = 200,
            BackgroundColor = Colors.White,
            Children =
            {
                new ActivityIndicator
                {
                    IsRunning = true,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                }
            }
        };
    }

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        // Prevent the back button from closing the page
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Update**

I forgot about your freezing problem. Your code left a lot of things to wish for. You need to learn Async/Await and start to use it in about everything. Read about it here [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios)

I am not able to test and verify your code in any way so I have updated on what I can see. I have made your methods Async and awaited what I believe needs to be awaited. By doing this you will allow the UI to be responisve and you will not lock up the program like you doing now. Since you know your program better you need to find the bottle necks and await them.

Here we go.

```cs
public async Task RiempioSettimana(DateTime DP)
{
    var page = new LoadingPage();
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);


    ModelloAgendaDisponibilita DisponibilitaSettimana = new ModelloAgendaDisponibilita;
    string DateInStriga = "";

    DateInStriga = "20" + L_Lun.Text[^2..] + L_Lun.Text[^5..^3] + L_Lun.Text[^8..^6];
    DisponibilitaSettimana = await ScaricoGiorno(DateInStriga);

    if (DisponibilitaSettimana != null)
    {
        if (DisponibilitaSettimana.Stato == "Libero") F_C1R1.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(ColoreLibero);
        else
         if (DisponibilitaSettimana.Stato == "Offerto") F_C1R1.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(ColoreOffertoMaLibero);

    }
    else
    {
        F_C1R1.BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(ColoreLibero);
    }
    await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
}


private async Task<ModelloAgendaDisponibilita> ScaricoGiorno(string DataInStringa)
{
    ModelloAgendaDisponibilita DR = new ModelloAgendaDisponibilita { Stato = "Vuoto" };

    DR = await Libreria.EstraggoModelloAgendaDisponibilita(UserNameRicevuto, path, DataInStringa);

    return DR;
}
public static async Task<ModelloAgendaDisponibilita> EstraggoModelloAgendaDisponibilita(string UserName, string path, string DataInStringa)
{
    FirestoreDb db = await FirestoreDb.CreateAsync("****");
    DocumentReference DocumentoEstratto = await db.Collection("***").Document(UserName).Collection(DataInStringa).Document(DataInStringa);
    DocumentSnapshot snap = await DocumentoEstratto.GetSnapshotAsync();
    ModelloAgendaDisponibilita DR = snap.ConvertTo<ModelloAgendaDisponibilita>();
    return DR;
}
```

Comment: Should ActivityIndicator be placed in an AbsolutLayer with a particular zindex? tnx

Comment: I would like to get closer to your second proposal but the problem remains the same: the screen freezes and refreshes only when the data download is complete. Can I enter the push call before downloading the data and the pop call immediately after downloading?

Comment: I have updated with a solution for your freeze problem as well. If you find this useful please upvote and approve it as the right answer. By doing this others with a similar  problem can find it more easily.

Comment: By better managing "async" and "await" everything started to work. Thank you very much for your advice. It was not a direct help (your code does not work) but you gave me important insights.

Comment: Glad I could help. My code do work but it of course just bare and need more to be of full use. We cannot test and do full features but as you said give you a possible way to do things to set you on your way. Happy coding. :)

Comment: Hi Peter. I tryed on macos and sometime there is this error: "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <CommunityToolkit_Maui_Core_Views_MauiPopup: 0x7f93e30af790>." 

On windows is perfect, on macos no...Can you help me please?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to open and close the page to many times, or that something is interfering with your code. It can have to do with that you still have problem with sync and async operations. It is coming from IOS/MacOS. Perhaps it is a good opportunity to start a new questions and show your new code and how it all turned out. :)

Comment: If you are sure you are truely using await as it should try launching it in the mainthread `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Navigation.PushModalAsync(page));` Try and see what happens.